# I need XML SQL query to get sum of nodes value based on another node value

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am struggling with this all day and still do not have desired output. I need a query as in title.

```
<aa>
  <bb>
    <cc>
      <typeid>2</typeid>
      <dd>
        <amount>10</amount>
      </dd>
    </cc>
    <cc>
      <typeid>2</typeid>
      <dd>
        <amount>20</amount>
      </dd>
    </cc>
  </bb>
</aa>
```

So my desire output would be 30, but it has to be based on the value type id, so pseudo code would be 
select sum(node to amount) from XML where (typeid node) = 2

I have tried:

```
SELECT t1.c1.value('sum(Amount)', 'float')
FROM @xmlCase.nodes('//aa/bb/cc') as t(c)
cross apply t.c.nodes('dd') as t1(c1)
WHERE t.c.value('typeId[1]', 'int') = 2
```

But in this case I have received two values: 10 and 20, but I need sum of those values.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way :

```
declare @xmlCase XML = '<aa>
  <bb>
    <cc>
      <typeid>2</typeid>
      <dd>
        <amount>10</amount>
      </dd>
    </cc>
    <cc>
      <typeid>2</typeid>
      <dd>
        <amount>20</amount>
      </dd>
    </cc>
  </bb>
</aa>'

SELECT x.value('sum(cc[typeid=2]/dd/amount)','float') as 'total'
FROM @xmlCase.nodes('//bb') bb(x)
```

Basically above query groups result at `<bb>` element level, and select sum of `<amount>` elements where corresponding `<typeid>` element equals `2`.

**Output :**

[image]

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/713)**

Comment: Wow, that works very well, my believing in stockoverflow is back because of you. Thank you very much @har07.